# Flutter. Overlaying pages when swiping

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In Flutter, I have found many animations for transitioning pages in PageView, but I cannot find any libraries to implement the effect shown in the video below in Flutter.

You can see a simple video on [this link](https://imgur.com/a/8YSec89)